# How to put running time constraints on rsync processes?

Tags: backup, rsync, time

I want to set a time limit on my rsync backup processes. How do I best go about?

According to [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/395552), there is an option to do exactly that:

```
--time-limit
When this option is used rsync will stop after T minutes and exit.
```

I do not have that option implemented on my Ubuntu 12.04, however. In the comments of the post, there is a possible solution hinted at, but I am not fluent enough to dare embark on that myself, just like that.

Also there seems to be [timelimit command/program](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/timelimit.1.html), but I do not have that either. Would that be the solution, perhaps?

Comment: Did you try installing timelimit: `sudo apt-get install timelimit`?

Comment: After all this time, `--time-limit` is still not merged and you have to apply the patch yourself and compile...

Comment: @muru: No, I thought I would get the recommendation from the community on which way is the preferred one before I embark on either option. Jan: Patch and compile is not really something I would do w/o a clear tutorial, so if you can hint me in the right direction, that would be terrific.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but the coreutils `timeout` command can do this (albeit it won't end gracefully).

```
timeout 60 rsync source destination
```

Where 60 is the time limit in seconds

Comment: +1, Yes the timeout command can be useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I patched it:

```
wget http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/rsync/src/rsync-patches-3.0.9.tar.gz
wget http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/rsync/src/rsync-3.0.9.tar.gz
tar xvf rsync-3.0.9.tar.gz
tar xvf rsync-patches-3.0.9.tar.gz
cd rsync-3.0.9
patch -p1 <patches/time-limit.diff
./configure
make
cp ./rsync /usr/local/bin
```

**NOTE:**  I had to patch `rsync` on both sides of my backup connection.

Answer (score 1):

### Shellscript

I made a bash shellscript, that iterates until everything is copied. When there are big files, it is important to use what was already copied in the previous  iteration, and it is nice to 'see' the progress of the copy process.

```
#!/bin/bash

########################################################################

function usage {

 echo "
Usage:   $0 source-dir/ target-dir  # copies content of source-dir
         $0 source-dir  target-dir  # copies source-dir (with subdirs)
"
 exit
}
########################################################################

# main

########################################################################

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
 usage
fi
if ! test -d "$1"
then
 echo "$1 is not a directory"
 if test -f "$1"
 then
  echo "but $1 is a file :-)"
 else
  echo "and $1 is not a file :-("
  usage
 fi
fi
if ! test -d "${2##*:}"  # allowing network directories
then
 echo "$2 is not a directory :-("
 usage
else
 echo "$2 is a directory :-)"
fi

cont=true
while $cont
do
 echo "copying ..."
 timeout --foreground 25 rsync --info=progress2 --partial -Ha "$1" "$2"  
 if [ "$?" != "0" ]
 then
  cont=true
  echo "flushing the buffers ..."
  sync
  echo "sleeping for 5 seconds ..."
  sleep 5
 else
  cont=false
 fi
done
echo "final flushing of buffers ..."
sync
echo "Dome :-)"
```

### Usage

When you make the shellscript executable and run it without any parameters, you get the following help message,

```
Usage:   ./rsyncer-w-pause source-dir/ target-dir  # copies content of source-dir
         ./rsyncer-w-pause source-dir  target-dir  # copies source-dir (with subdirs)
```

I tested the shellscript by copying some iso files with linux distros from a slow USB pendrive to my hard disk drive. This way there were several iterations, and the copying was interrupted in the middle of the iso files, but the copied part could be used by the next iteration. So I have checked that it works also to copy big files.

To be used for real copying, I think you should increase the time to copy (from 25 seconds), and you should also increase the time to sleep (from 5 seconds). Use the time intervals that are best for your particular task.

### Comments about the command line options and parameters

The command `timeout` stops the execution of the command it controls even when in the middle of copying a file.

```
   --foreground

          when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt,

          allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals; in  this
          mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out
```

The command `rsync` is a powerful copying command. See `man rsync` to get a complete description of the possible options.

```
   --info=FLAGS
          This option lets you have fine-grained control over the informa‐
          tion output you want to see.  An individual  flag  name  may  be
          followed  by a level number, with 0 meaning to silence that out‐
          put, 1 being  the  default  output  level,  and  higher  numbers
          increasing  the  output  of  that  flag  (for those that support
          higher levels).  Use --info=help to see all the  available  flag
          names,  what they output, and what flag names are added for each
          increase in the verbose level.  Some examples:

              rsync -a --info=progress2 src/ dest/
              rsync -avv --info=stats2,misc1,flist0 src/ dest/

   --partial
          By default, rsync will delete any partially transferred file  if
          the  transfer  is  interrupted. In some circumstances it is more
          desirable to keep partially transferred files. Using the  --par‐
          tial  option  tells  rsync to keep the partial file which should
          make a subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster.
```

You may or may not like the `--hard-links` option,

```
   -H, --hard-links
          This tells rsync to look for hard-linked files in the source and
          link together the corresponding files on the destination.  With‐
          out  this option, hard-linked files in the source are treated as
          though they were separate files.

   -a, --archive
          This  is equivalent to -rlptgoD. It is a quick way of saying you
          want recursion and want to preserve almost everything  (with  -H
          being  a  notable  omission).   The  only exception to the above
          equivalence is when --files-from is specified, in which case  -r
          is not implied.

          Note that -a does not preserve hardlinks, because finding multi‐
          ply-linked files is expensive.  You must separately specify -H.
```

Finally, read this explanation about the parameters (source and target),

```
          rsync -avz foo:src/bar /data/tmp

   This would recursively transfer all files from the directory src/bar on
   the  machine foo into the /data/tmp/bar directory on the local machine.
   The files are transferred in "archive" mode, which  ensures  that  sym‐
   bolic  links,  devices,  attributes,  permissions, ownerships, etc. are
   preserved in the transfer.  Additionally, compression will be  used  to
   reduce the size of data portions of the transfer.

          rsync -avz foo:src/bar/ /data/tmp

   A  trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid creating
   an additional directory level at the destination.  You can think  of  a
   trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory"
   as opposed to "copy the directory by  name",  but  in  both  cases  the
   attributes  of the containing directory are transferred to the contain‐
   ing directory on the destination.  In other words, each of the  follow‐
   ing  commands copies the files in the same way, including their setting
   of the attributes of /dest/foo:

          rsync -av /src/foo /dest
          rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo
```